# jQuery-UI - How to remove border and background from checkboxes

Tags: jquery-ui

Look of jQuery-ui checkboxes are fine but for an application I need to customize the appearance of a series (not all) of checkboxes on a form so they appears *without the border and the background*.

Any hint or working snippet of code is apreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you want to post the code you currently have?

Comment: Hint: use styling or adjust the theming.

Comment: I tried just what documented on official website.

Comment: Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve